# Calcular o produto cartesiano com programação funcional

Tags: python, recursão, programação-funcional

Estou escrevendo uma função em Python que recebe duas listas e retorna uma lista de tuplas com o produto cartesiano da função de entrada. Não posso usar nenhuma função pronta da biblioteca do Python.

Ex:

```
print(cartesiano([1,2],[11,22]))
# [(1, 11), (1,22), (2,11), (2, 22)]
```

Meu programa está imprimindo isso: `[(1, 11), (2, 22)]`. Não estou conseguindo arrumar a recursão.

```
def cartesiano(lista1,lista2):

def aux(l1,l2):
    if l1==[] and l2==[]:
       return []

    return [(l1[0],l2[0])] +aux(l1[1:],l2[1:])       

return aux(lista1, lista2)
```

Eu não posso usar laços de repetição, como é bem mais intuitivo. É uma questão de programação funcional, sem laços, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Numa abordagem que me lembra um pouco mais a funcional e a lógica, podemos pensar em cabeças de lista e corpo de lista. As antigas [funções `CAR` e `CDR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR) do [lisp](/questions/tagged/lisp) me veem a cabeça.

A função básica do produto cartesiano é descrita mais ou menos assim usando `CAR` e `CDR` (sobre listas de números):

```
produto_cartesiano(list1, list2):
  se list1 é lista vazia ou list2 é lista vazia:
    retorne {}
  senão se list1 não é lista:
    retorne { (list1, CAR(list2)) U produto_cartesiano(list1, CDR(list2)) }
  senão:
    retorne { produto_cartesiano(CAR(list1), list2) U produto_cartesiano(CDR(list1), list2) }
```

Em Python? Sem usar laços? Ainda não consigo pensar numa maneira direta. Mas podemos ter uma abordagem um tanto quanto mais [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog). Eu sei que o paradigma lógico não é exatamente o desejado, mas dá uma disfarçada. Ajuda a evitar os laços. Aqui, a questão é passar como argumento a lista de retorno. No paradigma lógico você não construiria a lista, você inferiria a lista, é uma questão bem diferente. Aqui, realmente inseriremos os resultados na lista de retorno. Então, podemos fazer o produto cartesiano assim:

```
def produto_cartesiano(lista1, lista2, resultado = []):
  if lista1 == [] or lista2 == []:
    return resultado
  elif !isinstance(lista1, list):
    resultado.append((lista1, lista2[0]))
    return produto_cartesiano(lista1, lista2[1:], resultado)
  else:
    produto_cartesiano(lista1[0], lista2, resultado)
    return produto_cartesiano(lista1[1:], lista2, resultado)
```

Note que estou usando `CAR` e `CDR` de jeito mais idiomático no Python, com `lista[0]` e `lista[1:]`.

Só relembrando aqui, essa resposta se aplica a listas de números. Não se aplica a conjuntos generalizados, incluindo conjuntos que podem ter outros conjuntos como seus elementos.

---

No sua resposta, você andou ao mesmo tempo nas duas listas na chamada recursiva, mais ou menos assim:

```
cartesiano(l1, l2):
  se l1  é lista vazia e l2 é lista vazia
    return {}
  return { (CAR(l1), CAR(l2)) U cartesiano(CDR(l1), CDR(l2)) }
```

Isso elimina muitos elementos do resultado. Seja `L1 X L2` o produto cartesiano, você está eliminando os subconjuntos `CDR(L1) X CAR(L2)` e `CAR(L1) X CDR(L2)`, e também alguns outros subconjuntos devidos à recursão. Sua condição de parada também está estranha, pois a [definição de produto cartesiano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) diz que, se um dos conjuntos for o conjunto vazio, o resultado também será vazio. Isso significa que deveria ser um **OR**, não um **AND**.

A grosso modo, um produto cartesiano seria composto dos seguintes subconjuntos:

```
L1 X L2 =
    ({CAR(L1)} X {CAR(L2)}) U
    ({CAR(L1)} X CDR(L2)) U
    (CDR(L1) X {CAR(L2)}) U
    (CDR(L1) X CDR(L2))
```

Se notar bem, `({CAR(L1)} X {CAR(L2)}) U ({CAR(L1)} X CDR(L2)) = {CAR(L1)} X L2`; e semelhantemente para `(CDR(L1) X {CAR(L2)}) U (CDR(L1) X CDR(L2)) = CDR(L1) X L2`

Portanto, temos que:

```
L1 X L2 =
    ({CAR(L1)} X {CAR(L2)}) U
    ({CAR(L1)} X CDR(L2)) U
    (CDR(L1) X {CAR(L2)}) U
    (CDR(L1) X CDR(L2)) =
    ({CAR(L1)} X L2) U
    (CDR(L1) X L2)
```

Notou a semelhança com a minha recursão?

---

Agora, e para conjuntos generalizados? Conjuntos generalizados contém conjuntos dentro de conjuntos.

Pegando a fórmula completa:

```
L1 X L2 =
    ({CAR(L1)} X {CAR(L2)}) U
    ({CAR(L1)} X CDR(L2)) U
    (CDR(L1) X {CAR(L2)}) U
    (CDR(L1) X CDR(L2))
```

O caso conhecido da recursão é com os conjuntos vazios. Mas, também posso afirmar que, como `CAR(L)` retorna um elemento pertencente a `L`, temos que `{CAR(L1)} X {CAR(L2)}` é igual ao conjunto unitário `{[CAR(L1), CAR(L2)]}` cujo elemento é a tupla formada pelos primeiros elementos de `L1` e `L2`.

Sendo assim, a fórmula recursiva para ambos os conjuntos não vazios:

```
L1 X L2 =
    {[CAR(L1), CAR(L2)]} U
    ({CAR(L1)} X CDR(L2)) U
    (CDR(L1) X {CAR(L2)}) U
    (CDR(L1) X CDR(L2))
```

Portanto, a função recursiva seria:

```
def produto_cartesiano(l1, l2, resultado = []):
  if l1 == [] or l2 == []:
    return resultado
  else:
    car1 = l1[0]
    cdr1 = l1[1:]

    car2 = l2[0]
    cdr2 = l2[1:]

    resultado.append( (car1, car2) )
    produto_cartesiano([ car1 ], cdr2, resultado)
    produto_cartesiano(cdr1, [ car2 ], resultado)
    return produto_cartesiano(cdr1, cdr2, resultado)
```

Comment: Eu também  não posso usar variáveis. Mas já deu certo. :)